# Jqwidget Treegrid

Tags: html, treegrid, jqwidget

this is might clearer:
I have billion records data for treegrid, I use plugin jqwidget treegrid  using "virtual mode", but the editing proccess for update data does not work in term it doesn't send data to server.
How can I fix the problem.

Or I have to change the plugin, could you give me some recomendations to find the best plugin for treegrid.

this is my code

$("#jqxTreeGrid").jqxTreeGrid({
        width: '100%',
        icons: true,
        autoRowHeight: true,
        showHeader: true,
        columnsHeight: 30,
        columnsResize: true,
        columnsReorder: true,
        filterable: true,
        filterMode: 'advanced',
        sortable: true,
        pageable: false,
        pagerMode: 'advanced',
        altRows: true,
        showToolbar: true,
        showStatusbar: true,
        toolbarHeight:35,
        editable: true,
        editSettings: { saveOnPageChange: true, saveOnBlur: true, saveOnSelectionChange: true, cancelOnEsc: true, saveOnEnter: true, editSingleCell: false, editOnDoubleClick: true, editOnF2: true },
        pageSizeOptions: ['5', '10', '25', '50', '100', '200', '500', '1000'],
        virtualModeRecordCreating: function (record) {
            if (record.is_leaf) 
            {
                record.leaf = true;
            }
        },
        virtualModeCreateRecords: function (expandedRecord, done) {
            var source =
            {
                dataType: "json",
                dataFields: [
                    { name: 'group_pin', type: 'string'},
                    { name: 'root_of', type: 'string'},
                    { name: 'user_pin_owner', type: 'string'},
                    { name: 'name', type: 'string'},
                    { name: 'name_alias', type: 'string'},
                    { name: 'url', type: 'string'},
                    { name: 'avatar', type: 'string'},
                    { name: 'type', type: 'string'},
                    { name: 'address', type: 'string'},
                    { name: 'icon', type: 'string'},
                    { name: 'is_leaf', type: 'bool'},
                    { name: 'description', type: 'string'}
                ],
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                id: 'group_pin',
                hierarchy:
                { 
                    keyDataField: { name: 'group_pin' },
                    parentDataField: { name: 'root_of' }
                },
                url: 'http://localhost/app/listdata',
                root: "listData",
                addRow: function (rowID, rowData, position, parentID, commit) {
                    commit(true);
                    newRowID = rowID;
                },
                updateRow: function (rowid, rowdata, commit) { 
                    $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: 'http://localhost/app/save',
                       dataType: 'json',
                       data: $.param(rowdata),
                       error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            commit(false);
                       },
                       success: function(data, textStatus){
                            if(data['response'] == true)
                            {
                                commit(true);

```
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            commit(false);
                        }   
                   }
                });
            }
        }; 
        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source,{
            beforeSend: function (xhr) { },
            downloadComplete: function (data, status, xhr) { },
            loadComplete: function (data) { 
                done(dataAdapter.records);
                $("#clearParentGroupbuttom").addClass("disabled");
                if(data.listData.length > 0)
                {
                    for(var i=0; i<data.listData.length; i++ )
                    {
                        if(data.listData[i].root_of != '')
                        {
                            $("#jqxTreeGrid").jqxTreeGrid('expandRow', data.listData[i].root_of);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            beforeLoadComplete: function (records) { },
            loadError: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                done(false);
            },
            formatData: function (data) {
                if (expandedRecord == null) 
                {
                    data.parent_code = ""
                }
                else 
                {
                    data.parent_code = expandedRecord.group_pin;
                }
                var pageSize = $('#jqxTreeGrid').jqxTreeGrid('pageSize');
                return data;
            }
        });
        dataAdapter.dataBind();
    },
    columns: [
        {
            text: 'Name', 
            pinned: true,
            dataField: 'group_pin',
            editable: false,
            align: 'center',
            hidden: true,
            sortable: true,
            filterable: true,
            width: 150
        },{
            text: 'Name', 
            pinned: true,
            dataField: 'name',
            align: 'center',
            minWidth: 200,
            width: 350,
            cellsRenderer: function (rowKey, column, cellValue, rowData, cellText) {
                return cellValue + " (<b style='font-size:10px;'>Pin: " + rowData["group_pin"] + "</b>)";
            },
            validation: function (cell, value) {
                if (value == "")
                {
                    return { result: false, message: "<?php echo trans('garputala.required_textbox'); ?>" };
                }                             
                return true;
            }
        },{
            text: 'Owner', 
            pinned: true,
            dataField: 'user_pin_owner',
            editable: false,
            hidden: true,
            align: 'center',
            cellsAlign: 'center',
            width: 100
        }
    ]
});
```

Thanks
Rido

Comment: This seems very unclear. Can you clarify what the problem is that you're facing, perhaps show some code?

Answer (score 1):

You should implement "updateRow" function in the [TreeGrid's](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtreegrid/index.htm) source object. There you should make AJAX call to send the updated data to your server. Below is a sample definition of "updateRow".

```
 updateRow: function (rowID, rowData, commit) {
                     // synchronize with the server - send update command
                     // call commit with parameter true if the synchronization with the server is successful 
                     // and with parameter false if the synchronization failed.
                     commit(true);
                 }
```